# How to get an archive page meta?

Tags: meta-query, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

Im trying to get some meta from the plugin Yoast Seo, set to a archive page of a custom post-type. What am I doing wrong?

```
$titleSEO = get_post_meta( '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true);
```

Comment: archives do not have meta, only individual terms users comments and posts can have meta, not lists/archives

Answer (score 0):

From the [get_post_meta() function reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/),

> Retrieves a post meta field for the given post ID.

The function is inteded to be used with posts (any type), not post type archives. You'll need to dig into the [documentation provided by the plugin author](https://developer.yoast.com/customization/apis/overview) to find out, how to retrieve meta data for a post type archive.